# cocos2dx android studio edit configuration

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cocos2d-x

I had install all `cocos2dx` requirements for that . when I create an cocos2dx project this directory's created :
[image]

now I want to open it on the android studio . now when I open the `proj.android-studio` I can't run project and it's need to `edit configuration` . now which  configuration should i do for run this hello world game  ?
and consider this I am completely new in cocos2dx .
thanks for any help

Comment: Open cmd in proj.android-studio folder, and exec `cocos compile -p android --android-studio`. And then open android studio, import again.

Comment: Android studio does not provide good support for c++ projects. Infact I personally use visual studio for development of cocos2dx projects and compile for android using the command above

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't a strong support for the Android Studio. You should first compile using

> cocos compile -p android --android-studio

You should run this command in the projects home directory (that contains `Classes`, `proj.android-studio`... folders)

After running this, cocos will create an `.apk file` in the `bin/debug` folder.

You can try to run this `.apk` on your device or to get different builds you can import the `proj.android-studio` to the `Android Studio` and change the settings. But whenever you change a file in the classes folder, you have to compile it again.

For convenience, I am keeping two IDE (`Visual Studio` and `Android Studio`) and command line open. I am editing my c++ files in `Visual Studio`, I am compiling the code through command line, then I am trying to debug with `Android Studio`.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop your project in command promte.Then run "cocos compile -p android --android-studio".For more information refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdOkbXYsf04) video link

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use Android Studio for game development using Cocos2dx

Requirements -

1. Cocos2dx-3.16
2. Android Studio (v3.0.1)
3. Update Android SDK (Update API 23 to API 19) Recommended
4. NDK r14b (Do not use r16. It has compatibility issue with cocos2dx)
5. python (2.7.14)

Steps-

1. Install python ( While installation use Add path to all local hard
   drive )
2. Read readme.md file to configure the basic requirements for project ( Like setting environment path )
3. Create new Cocos2dx cpp project
4. Import the proj.android-studio folder into Android Studio
5. Change the supported platform. If you got any error
6. Configure project settings. Click Open->Project structure and put Min and Max API support
7. Modify Android.mk. Refer this
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045723/2052113
8. Build project
9. Run Project ( Your sample android game is ready )