# Cocos2d-x on Android Studio - New CPP files are not listed

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, ndk-build

### Android Studio 2.3.3

### Cocos2d-x 3.15.1

It's my first experience with **Cocos2d-x** Game Engine, I encountered a lot of problems. The first time I tried the latest **NDK** of Android Studio but there is a bug on this **NDK** version when I tried to compile my project with : `cocos compile -p android --android-studio`  so I change the **NDK** version to 13b.

When I changed to **NDK 13b** the compilation was done without any problems and android studio build my project successfully but when I tried to create **new CPP FILE** or JAVA FILE or anything inside the **Classes folder**, Android Studio It does not display anything except the first **CPP FILES**, then I changed again **NDK to 14b** and I encountered the same problem.

The **CPP** files exist on my disc but Android Studio could not detect the files I created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, the solution is to using Wildcards eliminates and modify **Android.mk** each time you add a file inside Classes folder.

like this :

```
...
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libMyGame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_JNI_PREFIXED := \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes/**/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes/**/**/*.cpp)  

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES_JNI_PREFIXED)
...
```

If you add a new cpp file, you need to update Android.mk

In addition, please run “Build > Refresh Linked C++ Projects” of Android Studio menu.

Answer (score 1):

If found another solution to add all files, without modifying Android.mk each time you add a file inside Classes folder.

```
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp

    FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes/*.cpp)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes
```

To add other cpp files from another folder you can use ( LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ) just change directory name according to yours.

```
    FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../DirectoryName/*.cpp)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```